# Do I need to have Java (IcedTea) Installed on my machine?

Tags: java

Do I need to have Java installed on my machine? The website (Blackboard) that my school uses says that I need to have Java installed, but everything seems to be working fine without it. Running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, default Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is probably just checking for Oracle's implementation of Java and since it does not find it it complains you need to install it.

That happens a lot with bad programmed sites that require Java, ie: one of those seems to be my NAS web interface, everything works the same as my Windows laptop with Oracle Java, nothing is different, still it complains I need Java installed

[image]

If everything is running then that is a sign you have Java (probably the open source OpenJDK implementation) and if you have no complaints I would say its more than save to ignore the warnings you get.

Make sure you tick any box with the option *Don't annoy me again* and move on, you can start thinking about it if anything seems wrong later on.