# Why does Chrome report java as old, even though I have the newest version?

Tags: java, google-chrome

I have the newest version of Oracle Java (1.7.0_05) from Webupd8's PPA.

Despite this, Google Chrome complaints that my Java plug-in is out dated, and forces me to confirm that I want to run every applet I have to use (like my bank and such).

Can anyone please tell me why this is?

Did Google screw up, or am I just in plain bad luck?

-- Edit --
(Upon request)
I basically installed Java this way:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

This works excellent for Firefox, but Chrome complains about the version.
I have tried OpenJDK 7, but it both reports being too old in Chrome, and  furthermore it won't load it at all.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173553/do-i-need-to-have-java-icedtea-installed-on-my-machine/173554#173554

Comment: This bug is related to the plugin not loading: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/1025553

Comment: And this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/1035573

Answer (score 1):

Could you please update your question and let us know what you did to install Java

I had a similar issue but I used the following command in Ubuntu Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

If you install this from Ubuntu's Software Center it will most likely install an add-on (icetea-netx). Make sure that it's selected before you hit install (in Ubuntu's Software Center). This will install Open Java 7 Runtime Environment with IceTea Netx (see http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/IcedTea-Web).

JDK is Java Development Kit and is not really required unless you are into developing Java programs.

Comment: Note that he installed Oracle Java so he probably does not want OpenJDK...

Comment: Yep I understand, Thanks for that izx, but my point is that this version worked on Chrome (for me) and I can use all the banking and other sites that require Java runtime.

Comment: Updated the question above. I basically don't care too much whether using Oracle Java or OpenJDK, as long as Chrome just runs it instead of requiring me to permit it to run every time.
Oh, btw I have a MSc in Computer Science, so just fire away with some command line ;)

Comment: I know about JDK too btw.

Answer (score 1):

Please try installing Oracle Java 7 *the official way*, i.e. downloading the binary installer from *oracle.com* instead of via a PPA.

AFAIK that definitely installs the updated browser plugin so that the browsers (at least Firefox for sure) can detect and use it.

Comment: I think the  PPA actually downloads the installer from Oracle and runs it automatically (at least that's what it advertises).
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You may have one version on your system, but a certain browser could be using other.

You should point chrome to the right java version, point the location of your libpnpjp2.so to chrome plugins.

Something like this:

> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins

Comment: Could you perhaps give me something usable on 12.04? The file libnpjp2.so isn't on my system.

Comment: My Chrome installation didn't have the plugins folder...

Comment: Did you made a link to it? Like i posted above?

Comment: I can't make the link since the target doesn't exist.

Comment: The target i gave you is an example. Have you tried locating libnpjp2.so in your pc? For example, `sudo locate libnpjp2.so `